# Search and match multiple fields in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, postman, dsl

I'm using Elasticsearch for search for multiple fields. I would like to match with multiple fields using operator `AND`.

My code is here.

```
http://192.168.1.102:9200/storedevents/_search

GET

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "aggregateid": 163
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "entity": "Fornecedor"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My Data:

```
id:0bad3af6-0a2b-4cce-a55a-6a5b19ced03f data:{"Id":163,"CreatedAt":"2019-11-07T10:48:07.0809551","UpdatedAt":"2019-11-13T17:12:32.0463481-03:00","DeletedAt":null,"PessoaId":163,"StatusFornecedorId":2,"FornecedorPrincipalId":303,"IntegracaoId":2511361,"IdReduzido":"SFLTDA","Ativo":true,"RazaoSocial":"SINTER FUTURA LTDA","NomeFantasia":"SINTER","Cnpj":"74222563000241","Timestamp":"2019-11-13T17:12:32.1168883-03:00","Entity":"Fornecedor","MessageType":"FornecedorEditedEvent","AggregateId":163} user: - timestamp:Nov 13, 2019 @ 18:12:32.128 entity:Fornecedor messagetype:FornecedorEditedEvent aggregateid:163
_id:0bad3af6-0a2b-4cce-a55a-6a5b19ced03f _type:storedevent _index:storedevents _score: -
```

[Response is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABvvx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Fields name are case sensitive.
I assume you auto map your documents (so the fields you are looking for are indexed)

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "AggregateId": 163
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "Entity": "Fornecedor"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: return is empty :(

Comment: It will be good, if you can share mapping of the corresponding index.